# Suggest Data Structure which implement this

Tags: data-structures

Can any one suggest any data structure/code such that if we map 1 to a, 2 to b, 3 to c i.e.

```
1 --> a
2 --> b
3 --> c
```

then we can also reverse lookup such as if i query 'a' then it should output 1 and similarly 2 and 3 for 'b' and 'c' respectively.

Also if i change the mapping afterwards from above mapping to :

```
1 --> a
2 --> a
3 --> c
```

then after reverse  lookup i should get (1,2) for 'a' and (3) for 'c'.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number to letter direction:  a hash.
For the letter to number direction:  multimap (or a hash where each value is a list)

Comment: List will increase the complexity of my solution...Anything other??

Comment: If I give you an 'a' the result is 1 or 2  Somehow somewhere the caller has to be told that.  Note that it's not a proper mathematical function.